# Interesting full-text-search Behaviour

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

Crating table

```
CREATE TABLE `Footable` (
    `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `foo_colmn` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FULLTEXT (foo_colmn),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Insert some row

```
INSERT INTO Footable (`foo_colmn`) VALUES ("against1111 , against");
INSERT INTO Footable (`foo_colmn`) VALUES ("against1111");
INSERT INTO Footable (`foo_colmn`) VALUES ("against");
```

And search with BOOLEAN MODE

```
SELECT * FROM Footable WHERE MATCH 
    (foo_colmn)
AGAINST
    ('against1111' IN BOOLEAN MODE);


-------------------------
id |foo_colmn           |
---|--------------------|
1  |against1111 , against |
2  |against1111           |
```

Yeah thats prity normal but if i search the "against"

```
SELECT * FROM Footable 
    WHERE MATCH 
        (foo_colmn)
    AGAINST
        ('against' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

---------------
id |foo_colmn |
---|----------|
```

Return nothing. I can't understand what's going on. (Sory about my poor English)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn about stop words (and short words).

Stop words are words that are common or deemed not useful, so they are removed from the index.  There is a standard list included with MySQL.  "Against" would be a typical stop word (and "is", "the", "a", "nevertheless", etc.).

You can read about them [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-stopwords.html).

The solution is to rebuild the full text index with no stop words (or with a custom list).

Edit.

I should note that for some (now doubt brilliant) reason, InnoDB stop words are different from MyISAM stop words.  So, I can make a guess that you areusing MyISAM, because "against" is in only one list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Out off topic why there is a stop words list. if i can delete all of them what will happen?

Comment: @kahredici . . . I don't know the answer to your question.  Stop words lists have been around since automated text analysis began.  I suspect that they are a legacy as a performance improvement to reduce the size of inverted indexes.